# Finding out where analytics should be defined

Tags: python, python-2.7, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am working with Google Analytics api in python and keep getting the error

```
NameError: name 'analytics' is not defined.
```

I have been searching for several days on the `analytics` api site and on StackOverflow for the answer. If someone could please point me in the direction of the right documentation or help me out here that would be greatly appreciated. Attached is the code that I have so far.

```
from apiclient.http import MediaFileUpload
from apiclient.errors import HttpError

try:
  media = MediaFileUpload('Bing_Ad_Test.csv',
                          mimetype='application/octet-stream',
                          resumable=False)
  daily_upload = analytics.management().uploads().uploadData(
      accountId='',
      webPropertyId='',
      customDataSourceId='',
      media_body=media).execute()

except TypeError, error:
  # Handle errors in constructing a query.
  print 'There was an error in constructing your query : %s' % error

except HttpError, error:
  # Handle API errors.
  print ('There was an API error : %s : %s' %
         (error.resp.status, error.resp.reason))
```

Comment: Got the exact same issue. Couldn't find an answer !

Comment: Can you provide a link to the boilerplate code you used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is saying what is happening: you did not define the name `analytics` used in line 9 previously

```
daily_upload = analytics.management().uploads().uploadData(
```

You need to go over the first steps in order to use that and import it. You will also need an account since it requires auth.

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/service-py

After you setup, you should read

https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/coreDevguide

With that you should be ok!

Comment: I just tried this and im getting a new error AttributeError: 'MediaFileUpload' object has no attribute 'management'

Comment: Well, this fixed your error. Now this error is due to the incorrect usage of the packaged you are trying to use... I haven't use this MediaFileUpload library yet to know in depth how it is supposed to be used

Comment: Ok, I think I understood the library. I will update my answer

Answer (score 2):

The script that you are using assumes that you have already authenticated and created a service.  Before you can run this script, you need to build the service object.  See this example:

```
import argparse

from apiclient.discovery import build
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials

import httplib2
from oauth2client import client
from oauth2client import file
from oauth2client import tools
from apiclient.http import MediaFileUpload

# SET VARS
SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL='XXX'
CUSTOM_DATA_SOURCE_ID='XXX'
WEB_PROPERTY_ID='XXX'
ACCOUNT_ID='XXX'
CSV_IMPORT_FILE_LOCATION='XXX'
CREDENTIALS_KEY_FILE_LOCATION='XXX'

def get_service(api_name, api_version, scope, key_file_location,
                service_account_email):

  credentials = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_p12_keyfile(
    service_account_email, key_file_location, scopes=scope)

  http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())

  # Build the service object.
  service = build(api_name, api_version, http=http)

  return service

def uploadCSV(service):
  try:
    media = MediaFileUpload(CSV_IMPORT_FILE_LOCATION,
                          mimetype='application/octet-stream',
                          resumable=False)
    daily_upload = service.management().uploads().uploadData(
        accountId=ACCOUNT_ID,
        webPropertyId=WEB_PROPERTY_ID,
        customDataSourceId=CUSTOM_DATA_SOURCE_ID,
        media_body=media).execute()

  except TypeError, error:
    # Handle errors in constructing a query.
    print 'There was an error in constructing your query : %s' % error


def main():
  # Define the auth scopes to request.
  scope = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics.edit','https://www.googleapis.com/auth/analytics']

  # Authenticate and construct service.
  service = get_service('analytics', 'v3', scope, CREDENTIALS_KEY_FILE_LOCATION,
    SERVICE_ACCOUNT_EMAIL)

  # Upload CSV Data
  uploadCSV(service)


if __name__ == '__main__':
  main()
```